# How do I open a replay without logging in?

Tags: starcraft-2

On some of the Day[9] daily streams Shaun mentions a tool that allows him to open replays without the need to login (or maybe while the client is already open).

Right now if I click on a replay file while the game is not running I have to login. Otherwise, if the game is running already, nothing happens.

Please provide me some information on this tool, or an alternative.

Comment: I know hes talked about being able to view replays without owning starcraft 2 via the starcraft 2 starter edition. I haven't seen him talk about a tool to open replays without logging in though.

Comment: starter edition also requires login to b.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old versions of replays runs an old version of Starcraft 2 to display, when this is run you are logged out of battle net and there for no login is requred to watch replays of non current versions games, once the replay is done you are either logged back in or brought to the log in screen depending on where you where when you started the replay, also all social features associated with battle.net is turned off when watching old replays [source](http://us.blizzard.com/support/article.xml?locale=en_US&articleId=35110&pageNumber=1&searchQuery=replay)

Not sure if it is possible to watch replays for current version with out logging in because the game wants the social features turned on, but you can watch replays with a starter edition account. [source](http://us.blizzard.com/support/article.xml?locale=en_US&articleId=40075&pageNumber=1&searchQuery=replay)

If you don't want to install the game you can not see the replay, but the best solution i could find was [sc2gears](https://sites.google.com/site/sc2gears/), i haven't tested it but it looks ok.

only mention of a tool that enables you to watch replays was from beta, not sure if it has been updated and it also edited game files so would be against tos to use it.

Comment: hmm.. I'll try to reinstall my client

Comment: definitely requires login when I test it.

Comment: Just tested it with one from my unsaved folder and it required login, but for one of my old it didn't. Try this one  http://www.sc2replayed.com/replays/76319-1v1-terran-zerg-kulas-ravine